# OOP - what is top of the class hierarchy called

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following class hierarchy - class `A` derives from `B`, which derives from `C`, which derives from `D`.

What is `D` called? I don't want to call `D` a base class, because so are `B` and `C`. Is there a term in OO parlance that uniquely denotes that class which is the start of a hierarchy?

Comment: `D` is the base/mother/parent class of `A`, `B` and `C`. `C` is the base/mother/parent class of `A` and `B`. `B` is the base/mother/parent class of `A`. There is no specific term. As long as it's understood.

Comment: I'd go with root, which is analogous to the top most directory in a folder tree.

Answer (score 3):

I usually just describe it as the "root of the class hierarchy".

You could also say that it is a ["root class"](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-c/0596001177/ch05s05.html), which at least one book defines, albeit a book about C#, and possibly in a slightly different context, but, you know...

Pretty much anything involving the word "root" would be clear and understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the term "**Superclass**" or "**Parent** **Class**" instead of "Base class", which is also correct. You can say that D is the superclass of classes A, B and C. C is also the superclass of B and B is the superclass of A.

You can also describe it as the "Root Class", although there is no such terminology. I would not use this anywhere, but for the sake of giving them titles you could also say that class D is the great-grandfather of A, grandfather of B and father of C.